# SSRS web report missing rows

Tags: reporting-services

When my web report runs, it misses a few columns. I have setting to data element to output but does not fix the issue.

Example below is illustrates the issue counting number of days in each week. The data exists but Weeks 3 and 5 are missing day counts.

WEEK    1   2   4   6

DAYS    7   7   7   7

Comment: Check your dataset. Do you have points of data that fall in those weeks?

Comment: Make sure your query has values for these weeks, even if they are empty. You should be able to solve this in your select query by using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and catching null values like this for example: `ISNULL(COUNT(DayColumn), 0)`

Comment: There is data available for those days. This is a count of how many days are in a week. Week 3 and 5 both have 7 days in the data but do not show up on the report.